# Inject CSS for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am quite new to Chrome Extension development. I know it is possible to inject CSS. But is it possible to inject it for a specific URL. For example, whenever I visit google.com, the CSS will be injected.

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, you have 2 options, programmatic injection and content scripts. The names might sound really complicated and frightening, but don't worry ;)

[Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) will inject themselves automatically when the page is loaded. All you need to do (apart from writing the  script), is to specify something like this in your manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/"], //where your script should be injected
      "css": ["css_file.css"] //the name of the file to be injected
    }
  ]
}
```

This should inject the CSS every time you load google.com

Your other option is to use [Programmatic Injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi).
This can be useful if you want to inject the code only sometimes, usually from a background page. To do this, you can use [insertCSS()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-insertCSS). In that case, you'd need a [host permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings) in your manifest:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background_page": "myBackground.html", //if you want to inject it from a background page
  "permissions": [
    "background", //if you want to inject it from a background page
    "http://www.google.com/" // host permission to google
  ]
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: How to turn that on and off, let say you have a toggle in your popup to turn the CSS on and off? thanks