# For a Google Chrome extension, how can I create an on/off toggle in the browser icon?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, toggle

For example, Adblock has a "turn off" option when you click the browser icon in the dropdown.

I would like users to be able to toggle on/off my extension for a domain, instead of having to disable it to turn it off.

Another option could be to put a static button on the webpage layout and have that toggle the extension or stylesheet on/off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a 'browser_action' to the extension. You define it in the manifest.json as detailed [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/).

Use the *onClicked* event listener in your background script/page to disable/enable the application based on user clicks.
You can also use the same event handler function to make changes to the browser action icon or badge text to show the state change / current state to user.

---

Update Feb 2023:

When using manifest version 3, use `action` instead of `browser_action`. [Details here.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/)

Comment: Exactly what I need! But.. I need help implementing this. I understand the manifest part, but I need help with adding the javascript to define a different stylesheet, not just individual CSS. I have a full stylesheet I want to run on the page, when clicked, and to turn it off when clicked again.

Comment: specifically, in the example they have this: `chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      null, {code:"document.body.style.background='red !important'"});
});` but what I need to do is in that call define a .css stylesheet which is included in the extension.

Comment: To add a stylesheet to the webpage, use the manifest and add the manifest under the 'content_scripts'. See [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) for more details.

To implement switching on & off - if the css is small, an easy way would be to pass the on/off event from background page to content script which would then add/remove specific classes from page elements.

You can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118402/inject-css-for-chrome-extension) for a better, more detailed explanation of this and the other method.

Comment: Answer's linked browserAction URL is dead: see instead the updated [browserAction page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/)

Answer (score 0):

you could try a mixture of [local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153070/do-chrome-extensions-have-access-to-local-storage/2236898#2236898), a [toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) in a popup, and conditional statements surrounding your code

Answer (score -7):

Abraham, you could try and use this Chrome extension:

Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/niemebbfnfbjfojajlmnbiikmcpjkkja

You can use it to quickle enable/disable all your extensions.

I found this extension on this website:
http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/disable-all-extensions-in-chrome-with-a-single-click/

The article also mentions 2 extensions with which you can enable/disable an extension through a command in the URL box ("enable <>")

Comment: even though you mentioned some nice extensions, what the user asked was how to code the functionality while developing an extension himself :)